# How to read values from two children tags from a parent tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to create two variables 1) "Information_Header" for "< span class="label">" and 2) Information_Details for the text embedded in `<p>` excluding the `<span>`?

E.g. Information_Header = Venue
E.g. Information_Details = AmCham Office, 1 Scotts Rd, Shaw Centre #23-03 S(228208) - J&J Auditorium

```
for link in final_urls[:1]:
    webpage_response = requests.get(link)
    event = BeautifulSoup(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")
    title = event.find("h1").get_text()
    name = event.find("p", attrs={"class":"name"}).get_text()
    event_information = event.find("div", attrs={"class":"info"})
    raw_text = event_information.find_all("p")
    print(raw_text)
```

```
[<p><span class="label">Venue</span> <span class="divider">:</span> AmCham Office, 1 Scotts Rd, Shaw Centre #23-03 S(228208) - J&amp;J Auditorium</p>, <p><span class="label">Date</span> <span class="divider">:</span> July 09, 2019</p>, <p><span class="label">Time</span> <span class="divider">:</span> 11:45 AM -  1:30 PM </p>, <p><span class="label">Price</span> <span class="divider">:</span> $25.00</p>]
```

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Yup. https://www.amcham.org.sg/events-list/?item[date_start]=07%2F07%2F19&item[date_end]=01,10,19#page-1

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '''<p><span class="label">Venue</span> <span class="divider">:</span> AmCham Office, 1 Scotts Rd, Shaw Centre #23-03 S(228208) - J&amp;J Auditorium</p>, <p><span class="label">Date</span> <span class="divider">:</span> July 09, 2019</p>, <p><span class="label">Time</span> <span class="divider">:</span> 11:45 AM -  1:30 PM </p>, <p><span class="label">Price</span> <span class="divider">:</span> $25.00</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

data = []
for p in soup.select('p'):
    data.append([d.strip() for d in p.text.split(':', 1)])

for (header, info) in data:
    print('{: <10}{: <60}'.format(header, info))
```

Prints:

```
Venue     AmCham Office, 1 Scotts Rd, Shaw Centre #23-03 S(228208) - J&J Auditorium
Date      July 09, 2019                                               
Time      11:45 AM -  1:30 PM                                         
Price     $25.00
```

Comment: @JeffersonNg When I look at the text, I see that the information is stored in `<p>` tags. Inside these `<p>` tags the information is stored in format `<header>:<info>`. So I split the string with `str.split(':', 1)` method (note the 1 - that means I want to split just once). The first element of this split string is header, the second is our info.

Comment: How does the last line work? What does "{: <10}{: <60}" mean? Also how can I add a colon directly after the header?

Comment: @JeffersonNg Thats string formating syntax https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language To add colon you can do this for example `print('{: <10}{: <60}'.format(header + ':', info))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next_sibling` after selecting the class `divider` as this will take you beyond the `:` .

I show using an example event and with error handling.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.amcham.org.sg/event/8914/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
information_header = soup.select_one('.label')
information_detail = soup.select_one('.divider')
if information_header is None:
    information_header = 'Not listed'
else:
    information_header = information_header.text
try:
    information_detail = information_detail.next_sibling
except:
    information_detail = 'Not listed'
```